# Put a kink in x axis in seaborn or matplotlib - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution as to how in seaborn/matplotlib I can put a kink in the x-axis like the one shown in the figure

[image]

Comment: Is any indicator of a broken axis good enough? Because in that case, given that every Seaborn figure has Matplotlib underlying it, you could start from the [example in the Matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-broken-axis-py).

Comment: You need to handle this at the matplotlib level, you can't do it directly with seaborn that is a higher level

Comment: @9769953  Can you please explain how to do this in the given context where the break is needed between origin the starting value? The above explains how to do it in between two graphs instead by creating ax1 and ax2. I am sorry but I am a little new to matplotlib.

Comment: @mozway have edited the question. Can you please explain if possible how to do it in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

The following approach:

- hides the [spine](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html) representing the existing x-axis
- adds a dummy point for zero (e.g. at `x=40`)
- draws some lines for the kink, using `clip_on=False` to draw outside the main axes' area, and [`ax.get_xaxis_transform()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis_transform.html) to use ["data coordinates"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for `x` and "axes coordinates" for `y` (`0` at the bottom and `1` at the top); the thickness and line color are copied from the spine
- shows the dummy zero position as `0`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(50, 89, 80)
bins = np.arange(50, data.max()+6, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))

ax.hist(data, bins=bins, fc='skyblue', ec='navy')
false_zero = bins[0] - 10
ax.set_xticks(np.append(false_zero, bins))
ax.set_xticklabels(np.append(0, bins))

for spine in ['top', 'right', 'bottom']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
ax.add_line(plt.Line2D(xdata=[false_zero, false_zero + 2, false_zero + 4, false_zero + 4, false_zero + 6, bins[-1] + 1],
                       ydata=[0, 0, 0.1, -0.1, 0, 0],
                       color=ax.spines['bottom'].get_edgecolor(), lw=ax.spines['bottom'].get_linewidth(),
                       clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform()))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: x axis with a kink]

PS: For the kink of the original post:

```
ax.add_line(plt.Line2D(xdata=[false_zero, false_zero + 2, false_zero + 2, false_zero + 6, false_zero + 6, bins[-1] + 1],
                       ydata=[0, 0, 0.1, -0.1, 0, 0], ...))
```

[image: original kink]

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Absolutely perplexed how this hasn't got any upvotes, it's a great answer.